# C if statement with && - Which function will execute first?

Tags: c, if-statement

If I have an if statement in C that looks like:

```
if( function1() > 0 && function2() > 0 ){

    //blah

}
```

Which function will execute first and will it always execute in that order?

Comment: Wouldn't function1 executes before function2, and it will always be in that order. If function1 fails then function2 won't be executed at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here `function1()` is *guaranteed* to execute first.

The `&&` operator is a [short-circuiting operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). `function2()` won't even be called unless the result of `function1()` is greater than zero.

From the C99 standard:

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand
>   compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

Comment: Isn't that backwards? If `function1() > 0` is true, then `function2` must be called.

Answer (score 3):

`function1`, and yes. `function2` will be called if and only if the previous condition is `true`.

<sub>This is called "short-circuiting", and it is essential, for example for a statement like this: `if (p != 0 && *p == 'X')` We can be certain that `p` never gets dereferenced if it is null.</sub>

Comment: Oops, I guess you meant true.

Answer (score 3):

`function1()` will be executed first and if its result is less than or equal to 0 `function2()` is not executed at all.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, function1 will always be executed first because you are using the && operator.

Additionally, if function1() > 0, function2 won't be called at all.

Answer (score 1):

This will evaluate from left to right. Check this out for [more info](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=465402)

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet `function1()` will execute first and `function2()` will execute **only** if first condition will give `true`.

You can easily check it out: add some printf in each functions and let `function1()` return 1.

Answer (score 0):

`function1()` will be called first. It is not the `if` which implies the ordering, but the `&&`: left operand is evaluated first, and the second operand is evaluated at all only if the left operand returned a non-zero value.