# Returning error when traversing through a tree

Tags: c, if-statement, return, codeblocks, avl-tree

I am trying to calculate the frequency of each node as I add them to the tree, instead of inserting a new element.  For some reason when a comparing a new key to every element in the current tree, the if statement will not return 1 if they are both identical.  BUT, the function will still add 1 to the frequency of the existing node.  This is very puzzling to me, as I don't know why it would skip over the return 1, and continue searching through the tree.  Thank you for help/advice in advance.

struct:

```
typedef struct node {
    char* key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int height;
    int frequency;
}node;
```

This is my parsing function:

```
while(fgets(str, 100, textFile)) {

    token = strtok(str," \n");

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        key = strdup(token);
            if((sameFrequency(root, key)==1)&&root!=NULL) { 
                printf("%s", key);
                free(key);
                token = strtok (NULL, " \n");
            }
            else {
                root = insert(root, key);
                //printf("%s\n", key);
                free(key);
                token = strtok (NULL, " \n");
            }
    }
    if(ferror(textFile))
    {
        printf("you done messed up a-a-ron");
        return(0);
    }
}
```

Function to check the frequency of each node:

```
int sameFrequency(node *node, char* key) {
    if (node != NULL) {

        if(strcmp(key, node->key)==0){ //This statement is true in some cases, but will not return the 1
            node->frequency = node->frequency+1;
            printf("%d\n",node->frequency);
            return 1;
        }

        sameFrequency(node->left, key);
        sameFrequency(node->right, key);
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Input would look something like this:

```
wrn69 flr830 flr662 flr830 flr830 
flr231
```

The output (after printing in preOrder):

```
key: wrn69, frequency: 1
key: flr830, frequency: 3
key: flr662, frequency: 1
key: flr231, frequency: 1
key: flr830, frequency: 1
key: flr830, frequency: 1
```

I want this to print everything shown, but I don't want the same key to be inserted into the tree, just incremement its frequency by 1.

TL;DR:  Function skipping over return value, but still running code in the if statement, have no idea whats wrong, even after debugging.

Comment: Is there more info that people would like provided, is it a bad question, or is it too hard to debug for the naked eye?  I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is trying to do, since you do not define your `node` struct, however your function `int sameFrequency(node *node, char* key)` has an obvious bug: not all code paths return a value.  Reformatting a bit for clarity, you can see that if `strcmp(key, key)!=0` then the return is undefined:

```
int sameFrequency(node *node, char* key) {
    if (node != NULL) {

        if(strcmp(key, node->key)==0){
            node->frequency = node->frequency+1;
            printf("%d\n",node->frequency);
            return 1;
        }
        else { 
            sameFrequency(node->left, key);
            sameFrequency(node->right, key);
            // Continue on out of the "if" statements without returning anything.
        }
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    // NO RETURN STATEMENT HERE
}
```

My compiler generates a warning for this:

> warning C4715: 'sameFrequency' : not all control paths return a value

Surely yours must be doing so as well, unless you intentionally disabled them.  Such warnings are *important*, and should *always* be cleared up before finishing your code.

I'm guessing you want to do something like this, perhaps?

```
int sameFrequency(node *node, char* key) {
    if (node != NULL) {

        if(strcmp(key, node->key)==0){
            node->frequency = node->frequency+1;
            printf("%d\n",node->frequency);
            return 1;
        }
        else { 
            int found;
            if ((found = sameFrequency(node->left, key)) != 0)
                return found;
            if ((found = sameFrequency(node->right, key)) != 0)
                return found;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This clears the compiler warning.

Incidentally, the following `if` statement is probably in the wrong order:

```
        if((sameFrequency(root, key)==1)&&root!=NULL) {
```

Since `&&` statements in C [execute left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300519/c-if-statement-with-which-function-will-execute-first) the following makes more sense:

```
        if(root!=NULL && (sameFrequency(root, key)==1)) {
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm going to test it right now.  I am using codeblocks and received no such error.  I compiled with the flags -WALL and -g, is there something else I should be using?  P.S, included the struct

Comment: @BestBenchBudd - maybe try the instructions here: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=134.0

Comment: Wow, ok I understand what I did wrong.  Thank you so much for this, it is working correctly now.  Just need to figure out how to balance the AVL Tree now!